Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar Selected Index Page Issue
I have a Problem with my Bottom Navigation Bar.
When I click on the IconButton in the Bottom Navigation Bar itself then the page changes to the coded one but the color remains the same (white) of the clicked index.
When I click on the area around the Bottom Navigation Bar item, then the color starts to change (orange) but the onPressed Method to change the site isn't called.

Does anyone know why?
My Code:
 class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyBottomNavigationBar({super.key});

    @override
    State<MyBottomNavigationBar> createState() => _MyBottomNavigationBarState();
}

    class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {
    int _selectedIndex = 0;
    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
   }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xffAEADB2),
            width: 0.3,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.orange),

        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        //fixedColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedFontSize: 14,
        unselectedFontSize: 14,
        enableFeedback: false,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        // onTap: _onItemTapped,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 24),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Page1(),
                  )),
            ),
            label: 'Page 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.devices, size: 24),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Page2(),
                  )),
            ),
            label: 'Page 2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 24),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  //_selectedIndex = 2;
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page3()),
                    (route) => false,
                  );
                });
              },
            ),
            label: 'Page 3',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings, size: 24),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Page4(),
                  )),
            ),
            label: 'Page 4',
          ),
        ],
        //currentIndex: 1,
        //onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
 }

My next try was:
I tried to replace the Navigator.actions inside the IconButtons with the method _onItemTapped and shifted the Navigator actions inside the _onItemTapped method via if statements lik this:
class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {
int _selectedIndex = 0;
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
setState(() {
  _selectedIndex = index;
  if (_selectedIndex == 2) {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page3()),
      (route) => false,
    );
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = 2;
      print(_selectedIndex);
    });
  }
      });
  }

But this also doesnt seem to work :(

I would prefer using only BottomNavigationBar's onTap

Instead of having nested tapEvent, you can use onTap from BottomNavigationBar and navigate based on index when ever necessary.
onTap: _onItemTapped,
items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 24),
    label: 'Page 1',
  ),

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    _selectedIndex = index; // if you like to change just after tap, no matter what route is
    setState(() {});

    /// now navigate based on index;  if or switch statement
    if (index == 0) {
      ///navigate to the newRoute
    } else if (index == 2) {}
  }


I updated the onTap-Method and refactored all IconButtons to Icons.
Also i updated my _onItemTapped method.
The jump from one page to another still works, but the colors doesnt change at all.
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
_selectedIndex = index;
setState(() {
if (_selectedIndex == 0) {
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeView()),
(route) => false,
);
}

is there any specific reason behind Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil instead of .push?

I think the problem is the Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()-Method.
Does it load the screen new that the _selectedIndex is again set to 0 because the page gets loaded again?

To answer your question I wanted to create a new navigation stack when u switch between sites via the navigation bar.
With the push operation you always get the opportunity to go back which i dont want in this situation

it removes when returns true from the callback,  Also you might just want to scaffold's body and show specific page based on index

I changed the method to .push and when the new site appears the bottomnavigationbar has still the same colors. When i go back via the arrow on the top left corner the bar changed although im already back on the old page. Thats weird.

Can you share a minimal version using dartpad

Sure, how can i provide Dartpad to you? Sorry, I'm new :/

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
